# После обновления компьютера перестал работать метод WebBrowser.ShowPrintPreviewDialog()

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, internet-explorer

Я использую в проекте webBrowser контрол. Всё работало, но после обновления компьютера ( ОС: windows 10) перестал работать метод ShowPrintPreviewDialog()
Диалоговое окно печати открывается, но оно пустое. При этом в свойстве DocumentText контент есть. Окно просмотра контента также открывается всё отображается правильно.

```
 webBrowser1.DocumentText = Content; 
 webBrowser1.ShowPrintPreviewDialog();
```

Подскажите в чём дело? Как возможно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ларчик просто открывался. Причина не работы метода ShowPrintPreviewDialog()
**Не был установлен принтер по умолчанию;)**

Answer (score 2):

Вот ссылка на MSDN:[WebBrowser.ShowPrintPreviewDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.showprintpreviewdialog(v=vs.90).aspx).
Тут есть такой текст:

### Platforms

> Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP SP2, Windows XP Media Center
>   Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows XP Starter
>   Edition, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server
>   2003, Windows Server 2000 SP4, Windows Millennium Edition, Windows 98
>   The .NET Framework and .NET Compact Framework do not support all
>   versions of every platform. For a list of the supported versions, see
>   .NET Framework System Requirements.

### Version Information

> .NET Framework Supported in: 3.5, 3.0, 2.0

Думаю, что Вам стоит накатить `.NET Framework 3.5` на свою систему. Либо откатить обновления до рабочей версии и ждать обновлений, которые все исправят.
Склоняюсь ко второму варианту, ибо он более правильный.

[Установка платформы .NET Framework 3.5 в Windows 8, Windows 8.1 и Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh506443(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: все же работал с NET Framework 4.5.1 и Windows10. И накатить версию 3.5 нет возможности так как в проекте используются сборки которых нет в этой версии

Comment: @VladimirTsybin, видимо обновления системы стали причиной отказа данного компонента. Зайдите в `Программы и компоненты`, затем на вкладку `Включение и отключение компонентов Windows` и попробуйте включить версию `3.5`. Я систему обновляю очень редко, поэтому у меня работает и на 8.1 и на 10.

Comment: @VladimirTsybin, ничего страшного и критичного не должно произойти, если Вы добавите 3.5 в систему. По крайней мере у меня ничего не происходило, делал это несколько раз.

Comment: вот ссылка где сказано, что он поддерживается в 4 версии [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfa0hawf(v=vs.100).aspx) ,но этого мало надо минимум 4.5

Comment: @VladimirTsybin, либо откатывать обновления, либо накатывать фрэймворк. Ну как-то другого решения пока не вижу. У Microsoft есть такая привычка - не поддерживать старый функционал, создавать новое и продвигать новое, хотите старого - ставьте старую версию. Ну, как-то так...

Comment: Вот эта https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh506443(v=vs.110) помогла, спасибо.

Comment: @VladimirTsybin, не за что! Отключите автоматическое обновление системы (если включено) и ставьте только проверенные и не сырые обновления.